# python regular expression replace two situations with one command

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to replace string like

```
'''1  2  3  4  5  6 abcde fghij klmno pqrst 7 8 9 10 uvwxyz abcdef 11 12 13'''
```

to

```
'''1  2  3  4  5  6
abcde fghij klmno pqrst
7 8 9 10
uvwxyz abcdef
11 12 13'''
```

that is my method:

```
s = re.sub(r'(\d) ([a-z])', r'\1\n\2', s)
s = re.sub(r'([a-z]) (\d)', r'\1\n\2', s)
```

how can I do this in `one regular expression`? and I know I can do it use `re.findall` and `groups` but I want to find a more easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it with a single regex:

- Use a conditional pattern. Capture `\1` is straightforward. Capture `\4` checks whether we grabbed `\2` or `\3`, and then defines the rest of the pattern accordingly.

  ```
  re.sub(r'((\d)|([a-z])) ((?(2)[a-z]|\d))', r'\1\n\4', s)
  ```
- Replace only the space, and surround it with look-behind and look-ahead assertions.

  ```
  re.sub(r'(?<=\d) (?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z]) (?=\d)', '\n', s)
  ```

But your two simple regexes are better than all of this nonsense.

Comment: @GuidoBouman Maybe you should be aware that using conditionals and/or lookarounds take slightly more time and resources than not using them! It's certainly negligible on a small scale though.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for noting. I find the lookahead & behind approach better as you only replace that part you actually need to replace. Which makes your code less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

I really think the easiest way would be to match using `findall` instead of splitting or `sub`-ing:

```
result = re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s+\d+)*|[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*", text)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

or in one line:

```
result = '\n'.join(re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s+\d+)*|[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*", text))
```

Gives:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
abcde fghij klmno pqrst
7 8 9 10
uvwxyz abcdef
11 12 13
```

`\d+(?:\s+\d+)*` matches the parts with digits and spaces.

`[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*` matches the parts with letters and spaces.

Comment: This just gives me another way to solve the problem, awesome and concise.

Comment: You might want to do [a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)* to match to letters and spaces

Comment: @XWen Right, that was an omission when moving the code here, good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.split`

```
>>> s = '''1  2  3  4  5  6 abcde fghij klmno pqrst 7 8 9 10 uvwxyz abcdef 11 12 13'''
>>> for i in re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+(?=\d)', s):
        print(i)


1  2  3  4  5  6
abcde fghij klmno pqrst
7 8 9 10
uvwxyz abcdef
11 12 13
>>> print('\n'.join(re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+(?=\d)', s)))
```

**OR**

`re.sub`

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])\s+(?=\d)', r'\n', s))
1  2  3  4  5  6
abcde fghij klmno pqrst
7 8 9 10
uvwxyz abcdef
11 12 13
```

The above `re.sub` command will replace one or more spaces which exists between digit and a letter or between a letter and a digit with newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression or command:

```
s = re.sub(r'((\d) ([a-z])|([a-z]) (\d))', r'\2\4\n\3\5', s)
```

It'll match or group 2 & 3 or group 4 & 5. =]

Comment: I get this when I run your code: `error: unmatched group`.

Comment: Ouch, which version of Python are you using?

This has been fixed recently: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/bd2f1ea04025

Comment: @GuidoBouman but it not work on Python 2.7, thank you all the same.

Comment: No problem, the other solutions are clearly better for your case. =]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a replacement:

```
re.sub(r'(\d[\d\s]*|[a-z][a-z\s]*)', r'\1\n', s)
```

To be more rigorous with trailing whitespaces, you can do that:

```
re.sub(r'(\d(?:[\d\s]*\d)?|[a-z](?:[a-z\s]*[a-z])?)\s*', r'\1\n', s).rstrip()
```