# How to use searched string as reference in substitution of python re?

Tags: python, regex

I am using following re to search a string that has number followed by character and it's working.

```
$re = ""[0-9][a-zA-Z]"";
```

However, I need to use searched data as reference in substitution and split it with space. Is there a way to use searched string in substitution.

For e.g.: How do I split the searched string with space? What substitution should be used?

I just need to know how to use the searched string as reference in substitution. For eg: "8A" should be "8 A" , "0A" should become "0 A"

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @thefourtheye They also aren't useful to people trying to answer them.

Comment: examples here may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300364/python-regular-expression-replace-two-situations-with-one-command

Answer (score 5):

Use [*capturing groups*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"([0-9])([a-zA-Z])")
>>> s = "Inches,85A,80A"
>>> pattern.sub(r"\1 \2", s)
'Inches,85 A,80 A'
```

Here we are capturing two parts of the input string - a single digit and a single letter. Then, using `re.sub()` to perform a substitution referring to the captured groups by number: `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is asking, so I can't tell if this is right.

Comment: @KSFT I think there was a question update and I think it should be clearer now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, it now is much clearer. I guess your answer does work. I'll upvote it.

Comment: re.sub(r'(reg1) (reg2)', r'\1 \2', string), don't forget r''

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Inches,85A,80A"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])', r' ', s)
'Inches,85 A,80 A'
```

The above regex matches the boundary which exists between a digit and an alphabet. Replacing the matched boundary with a space will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)